# what is the proper way to implement/use quill with node.js and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, user-interface, node-modules, quill

So I am trying to build myself a blog, and I want a UI for me to update a blog instead messing with the HTML files every time.

I am planning to get the content (blog content containing pics and text) from the quill editor (which is a delta object) then store it into MongoDB.

Then when I need to display it, retrieve it from the DB then render it dynamically using quill-render (https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-render).

The question is, since I don't know how quill is designed to work so can someone tell me if this is the proper way to do it? Or is it better to let quill somehow export the content to an HTML file, store it then simply redirect to it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to store and manipulate the `Delta` operations. We heavily rely on quill on [Wisembly Jam](https://jam.wisembly.com) and we manipulate live operations with ShareDB and store them more persistently inside PostgreSQL.

Simply use `quill.getContents()` to retrieve the `ops` (this is an array of operations, a simple JSON really easy to store).

Then, when you load your page, retrieve this JSON object from your DB, and use `quill.setContents()` to load it properly.

This is:

1) smaller to store than HTML
2) future proof (if Quill updates and changes things, it would still properly implement Delta format, not sure it would handle HTML the same way)

Answer (score 0):

The [quill](/questions/tagged/quill) documentation recommend's you to manipulate de editor data in the *Delta* format making it simple to save all your content in Json but, in the other hand you will have to depend on an thirty-party library to render it as HTML.

To use in Delta format, you will have to use [**`setContents()`**](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setcontents) and [**`getContents()`**](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getcontents). Saving in your DataBase as Delta (*See the Snippet in FullScreen for better visualization*):

```js
let quillEditor = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow'
});

quillEditor.on('text-change', function(){
  console.clear();
  console.log(quillEditor.getContents().ops);
});

//Retrieve your json from MongoDB
let myDocument = [{
    "insert": "Hello "
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "bold": true
    },
    "insert": "World!"
  },
  {
    "insert": "\n"
  }
];

quillEditor.setContents(myDocument, );
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css">

<div id="editor"></div>
```

Another approuch that I've used, is to retrieve the HTML directly from the editor with `QuillInstance.root.innerHTML`, that will allow you to save in your DataBase a direct HTML file, that you can render later:

```js
let quillEditor = new Quill('#editor', {
  theme: 'snow'
});

quillEditor.on('text-change', function(){
  console.clear();
  console.log(quillEditor.root.innerHTML);
});


//Retrieve your json from MongoDB
let myDocument = [{
    "insert": "Hello "
  },
  {
    "attributes": {
      "bold": true
    },
    "insert": "World!"
  },
  {
    "insert": "\n"
  }
];

quillEditor.setContents(myDocument);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css">

<div id="editor"></div>
```